# C# String format patterns for truncating numbers to two decimal places (e.g. money) or none in the case of trailing zeros

Tags: c#

How do I convert the following examples numbers (decimal, double or float) to 2 decimal places truncating (rounding down) the digits to the right:

```
77.1455
52.00
714.1554
5552.0001
```

Should become like these

```
"77.14"
"52"
"714.15"
"5552"
```

Some suggested

```
String.Format("G29");
String.Format("0.00");
```

But they don't work as expected.

Comment: Given your third block of code, it's unclear what you're trying to do. In the first two, it sounds like you're trying to produce a `string`, but in your third block you're assigning to `float`. Can you clarify the types involved and what the target type is?

Comment: What about trailing '9's?

Comment: What should 1.201 become, "1.2" or "1.20"?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar oh that's my fault, it is `string variable = String.Format();`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing it should be 1.20 but 1.2 also works fine, anyway Adam Cohen's answer works very well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "####.##" pattern to achieve the desired result with natural rounding (see bottom example for truncation).  Few examples:

```
var f1 = 1000.3455f;
var result = f1.ToString("####.##");
//result = 1000.35
```

Round's down eliminating trailing zeros:

```
f1 = 1000.0001f;
result = f1.ToString("####.##");
//result = 1000;
```

Add a comma if to the formatting string for comma separated numbers >= 1000:

```
var f1 = 1000.3455f;
f1.ToString("#,###.##");
//result = 1,000.35;
```

And if you want to remove the trailing numbers beyond hundredths without natural rounding:

```
var f1 = 1000.3455f;
f1 = (float)Math.Round(f1, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
result = f1.ToString("#,###.##");
//result = 1,000.34
```

Comment: [It's rounding up](https://rextester.com/CGMZVF67376).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar added bottom example for truncation.

Answer (score 5):

You can truncate the value after two decimal places:

```
(Math.Truncate(100 * value) / 100).ToString();
```

Full sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float[] values = { 77.1455f, 52.00f, 714.1554f, 5552.0001f };
    string[] formattedValues = Format(values);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, formattedValues));
}  

private static string[] Format(float[] values)
{
    return Array.ConvertAll(values, Convert);
}

private static string Convert(float value)
{
    return (Math.Truncate(100 * value) / 100).ToString();
}
```